# Rx equivalent of COUNT with GROUP BY?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

I have a list of recurring elements, say:

```
Observable<String> source = Observable.just("A", "B", "A", "C", "C", "A");
```

I would like to group them by their value along with how many times they appear, so the output would be pairs of:

```
{"A", 3}, {"B", 1}, {"C", 2}
```

Basically the equivalent of an SQL statement like `SELECT x, COUNT(1) GROUP BY x;`

I got only so far as to call groupBy on them:

```
source.groupBy(x -> x, x -> 1)
```

But this transforms the stream into GroupedObservables, and I couldn't find a good example how to move on with them. I tried `reduce()`, but it's not good here, since after `groupBy()` it wants to reduce the GroupedObservables, not the elements inside each group.

Is this possible with GroupedObservables? Is it possible any other way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Do you understand that if you had a hot observable or one that doesn't have an `OnComplete` signal that you can't do this computation?

Comment: No, I didn't think of that, but it seems understandable, thank you. Actually, I have the list emitted as a whole, not element by element in my case (I just simplified the code for the question), so I guess it's not a problem here, right?

Comment: Yes, but if it is a cold observable that emits all of its values you may not need Rx. What are you trying to do this for?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following code:

```
source.groupBy(val -> val)
    .flatMap(
        gr -> gr.count()
                .map(count -> new Pair<>(gr.getKey(), count)
    )
).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Would print out:

```
A=3
B=1
C=2
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use the `collect` or `collectInto` method,as shown below.

```
Observable<String> source = Observable.just("A", "B", "A", "C", "C", "A");

source.collectInto(new HashMap<String, MutableInt>(), (map, elem) -> {
    if (map.containsKey(elem)) {
    map.get(elem).increment();
    } else {
    map.put(elem, new MutableInt(1));
    }

}).subscribe(System.out::println);
```

By the way,if we were using [Reactor](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core),`collect` is the suggestive way of doing this,because in case of large number of groups,flatMap after groupBy will hang.

From the [javadoc of Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#groupBy-java.util.function.Function-)

> Note that groupBy works best with a low cardinality of groups, so chose your keyMapper function accordingly.
>   ...
>   Notably when the criteria produces a large amount of groups, it can lead to hanging if the groups are not suitably consumed downstream (eg. due to a flatMap with a maxConcurrency parameter that is set too low).

There is also an github [issue](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/931) related to this.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Observable<String> source = Observable.just("A", "B", "A", "C", "C", "A");
    Observable<KeyValue<String, Integer>> countStream = source
            .groupBy(val -> val)
            .flatMap(obs -> obs.count().flatMap(cnt -> Observable.just(new KeyValue<>(obs.getKey(), cnt))));

  private static class KeyValue<K, V> {

    private final K key;
    private final V val;

    public KeyValue(K key, V val) {
        this.key = key;
        this.val = val;
    }

    public K getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public V getVal() {
        return val;
    }
}
```